# React native app crashing android 13 production but fine on android 11

Tags: android, react-native, expo, location

I made a react app and it was working fine using the expo app to test it. I built in for production and on my phone I found it would open once and crash every other time if it would open after building. (I am using android 13) I sent it to a friend using android 11 and it works perfectly. I believe the problem is with one of the packages I am using.

So I have changed and some of the packages and added information in the `app.json` file as I have seen on other stackoverflow posts but have not had any luck.

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Finder",
    "slug": "finder",
    "version": "2.3.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "apple.spoonfinder.ml"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.im_the_tea_drinker.spoon_finder"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/icon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "2f14cfae-f990-4aab-9d8e-ca06ea8bec1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**These are the packages that I am using**

```
{
  "name": "finder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.8",
    "expo-cli": "^6.0.8",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-sensors": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Does any one know what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: It might have to do with the android permissions since google has updated policies in Android 12. Create an emulator Android 12 and test your local app on it with the --verbose flag.

Comment: So using the expo app on and  Android 12 emulator it works perfectly however running production crashs instantly again. i could not get the --verbose flag to work (im new to app development) However I found out about `adb logcat *:E` and i pasted the useful part in a past bin https://pastebin.com/zdf77JgC @TheMask

Comment: Try these methods: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26007#issuecomment-522882183

Comment: @TheMask I have added that to the top of my file so that start of my app.js looks like https://pastebin.com/vUcsS0X7. I am still getting crashes on startup

Comment: same issue on android 13 react-native-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was the expo sensor functions were some times returning undefined, to all we had to do is check if it was true. This was the fix.

```js
DeviceMotion.setUpdateInterval(200);
      DeviceMotion.addListener((motion) => {
        let heading = 0
        //check if heading is available
        if ( motion?.rotation?.alpha ) {
          heading = motion.rotation.alpha;
          heading = heading * (180 / Math.PI);
          heading = heading - angle;
          if (heading < 0) {
            heading = 360 + heading;
          }
          heading -= 90;


          setAngle(heading);
        }
        
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' 
implementation'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'}
```

And Build again

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue with your xml file. you have to set exported property to true.  this is an example of react-native cli. you have to do it with expo. I don't know much about expo.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">. <!--  this purports --> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Comment: So I have tried to add that to my app.json file as we don't have XML files when using JSON. This is the android section of the app.json incase you can see a mistake.  https://pastebin.com/Z8fyB6G5

Comment: try to search for this property. or try expo latest version .

Comment: Everything is up to date, and I found searching for the property. It opens for a second and then crashes still

Comment: create a debug apk and connect your device to android studio. and open logcar. you can check the crash logs

Answer (score 0):

Put this in manifest of Android Project.

`<manifest ...> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" /> </manisfest>`

And Build again.